# Добрый день, не выбирается в поле referenced id, id

Tags: mysql, sql

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите с базами данных, не выбирается поле id в referenced id

Comment: оно первичным ключом в той таблице сделано?

Comment: да, галочку ставил

Comment: Что значит "не выбирается" в списке же оно есть. И может тип данных не совпадает или первичным ключом не является. по картинкам этого не понять. руками напишите alter table .. add constraint ... foreign key и может по сообщениям об ошибке понятней будет что идет не так

Comment: галочка не ставится в том то и дело

Comment: в brand_id не ставится галочка

Comment: Показывайте CREATE TABLE обеих таблиц - и референсной, и реферальной. *в brand_id не ставится галочка* Скорее всего несовпадение типов.

Comment: поменял на INT, но все равно не выбирается

Comment: все спасибо, получилось